# How to prevent broken image appearing while loading my real image from server in head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on an application front-end with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, all is fine but before the image is loaded in the header, the broken image icon appears first.

[image: broken image]

I want to add a background color in place of broken image till original image  is fully loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show `<img>` after the content has been fully loaded.

```
<img style='display: none' onload="this.style.display = 'block'" src="...">
```

if you are using jQuery

```
<img style='display: none' id="myImg" onload="$(myImg).show()" src="...">
```

Comment: maybe this is not good with SEO If this style is in the html sent from server.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is not loaded when the page is initially rendered the img tag will display the icon. If you are using any JS then here is what you can do

1. Put the image tag in a condition and display it only when the image is loaded in the background (async calls).
   2 till the image is not loaded up hide the image tag and use a label or any other tag with the background color.

Comment: i tried but did'nt worked, is there trick to solve this with css?

Answer (score 1):

1)with css the solution is alt=" ".

2) with the help of java script

place this code in image tag

when before  image is fully loaded this will over come error by placing img in background

Answer (score 1):

Another method: use inline svg img placeholder, use ajax to request real img then repace placeholder.

inline img

```
<img alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```